# Adjusting image size on imageView and left bar button item

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

In my project I have 'change logo' option. 
[image]
On clicking this gray logo in front of Change logo, gallery opens up and user chooses a photo from it. This is done using the following code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    imgToBeSaved = image;
    self.imgViewChooseLogo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.imgViewChooseLogo.image = image;
    imageChanged = YES;
 }
```

Now this image is saved in documents directory. As this image should serve as a logo to all the view controllers. So i have set it as left bar button item using the following code:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[AppDelegate documentDirectoryWithFilePath]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
UIImage *new =  [AppDelegate  imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(150, 40)];
UIImage *new1 = [new imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:new1 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

where method scaledToSize goes as

```
    +(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

I have used 150*40 so that my default logo fits perfectly. Problem comes when i have to use some other image choosen from gallery. It stretches on the bar button item. I don't know how to set ratio of height and width of choosen gallery image so that image does'nt look weired on left bar button item.

Comment: if you don't want to stretch you should probably crop the image - right?

Comment: bt how would i know which portions of the image is to be cropped. I have been asked to adjust width and height of the image so that a photo picked from the gallery does'nt look distorted.

Comment: You should probably let your user decide that :D - see my answer

Comment: There are simple techniques (algorithms) to crop images to fit in a fixed frame. I think you should try one of those.

Answer (score 0):

You should let your user crop the image before you use it. Have a look at these frameworks (if you don't want to implement it yourself:

https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor

https://github.com/itouch2/PhotoTweaks

Comment: thanx for ur help bt dont u have any other way out. Some no cropping included method.